# What features differentiate Spacemacs from other editors and IDEs in terms that someone unfamiliar with both Vim and Emacs can understand?

Tags: spacemacs, documentation, learning

I am in the position of onboarding junior developers to Spacemacs but I am unable to find a detailed, canonical description of Spacemacs that is geared toward beginners.

Specifically, I don't find the Spacemacs documentation sufficient. "Emacs advanced Kit focused on Evil" tells the novice nothing useful, and the rest of the docs are equally lacking beginner context — they are solely written for an audience of current Emacs / Vim users.

Comment: isn't the [spacemacs site](http://spacemacs.org/) good enough an introduction?

Comment: I've updated my answer to specify that imo the current project documentation does not include an explanation/introduction for _beginners_ unfamiliar with both Emacs and Vim.

Comment: For people unfamiliar with both Vim and Emacs I'd say "Spacemacs is a text editor", maybe adding "powerful and highly configurable".

Comment: What I am after is: why would I used spacemacs over any of the other editors out there, what differentiates it from Emacs, Vim, SublimeText, VisualStudio Code, IntelliJ, etc.

What are the specific features of Spacemacs that differentiate it and recommend it over the many other powerful editors out there?

I've updated the title of my question to reflect this.

Comment: You can't differentiate spacemacs from emacs, since spacemacs is emacs. Which also means anything you can say about emacs also applies to spacemacs. You could boil that down to infinitely configurable/programmable/extendable, but getting more specific than that is hard, and highly dependent on your particular needs and uses.